# Js в консоли браузера работает, а из файла нет

Tags: jquery, консоль, javascript

Js в консоли браузера работает, а из файла нет.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $('.sf-with-ul').click(function(){
         console.log('clicked');
     });
});
```

Comment: Проверьте, подключается ли файл вообще, например перед document.ready добавьте alert()

Comment: В фаербаге посмотрите подключился ли файл к странице 

Comment: Да всё хорошо подключилось. Alert работать как до кода так и после, но вот если поставить внутрь, то не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Возможные причины ошибки:

1. Библиотека jQuery еще не загружена.
2. Элемент во время события ready еще не существует.

Попробуйте так:

```
 console.log($); // Проверка, загружена ли вообще jQuery
 $(document).on('click', '.sf-with-ul', function() {
      console.log('clicked');
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Возможно этот элемент появляется на странице после подгрузки через `AJAX`. Попробуйте так:

```
$(function(){ // тот же $(document).ready(), но короче
     $(document).on('click', '.sf-with-ul', function(event){ // вешаем событие на документ, что бы все добавленные элементы в процессе работы то же обрабатывались
         console.log('clicked');
     });
});
```

Ошибок в консоли нету? Может вы jQuery подключаете позже своего скрипта?